# Customize Popup Control in WPF with balloon style

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, styles

I am trying to implement Popup Control like below:

[image]

This has to be shown when MouseEnter event occurs on "Purple Question Mark" icon.

But I am unable to implement such Popup style as I am new to WPF.

Things I want to do as of now:

1. To show Popup on a relative location to purple "?" mark icon which is Right-Center of "?" icon.
2. To implement Popup style having such background like conversation balloon. I cannot hard code size of Popup as the length of text content inside may vary.

If anyone can help me achieving Popup Control with such style would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: As per your comments, you can handle the tooltip opening/closing in your `MouseEnter` and `MouseExit` event handlers.

You can use a tooltip and style it any way you like. This will give you appropriate "Pop-up" behavior. The behavior of the tooltip itself can be defined using the `ToolTipService` attached properties. This should get you started.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="_ellipse" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Purple">
    <Ellipse.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Your tooltip text."/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Right,Absolute"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.VerticalOffset" Value="40"/>
        </Style>
    </Ellipse.Resources>
</Ellipse>
```

Then, in your code-behind `MouseEnter` handler

```
private void _txt_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Ellipse thisSender = (Ellipse)sender;
    Tooltip tooltip = (ToolTip)thisSender.ToolTip;
    tooltip.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: I cannot use ToolTip as the application will run on a touch screen system, so User cannot do mouse over to see tooltip. It will always give click event if User touch the Purple Question mark icon.

Comment: @RobinPurbia, how do you expect the `MouseEnter` event to fire then, as per your question?

Comment: MouseEnter and MouseLeave events are working and I have tried it. I just want help making such Popup. Thanks for your prompt response.